# How to Sort By using J

Tags: arrays, sorting, j

I'm used to *sort by* operation which many languages afford. It takes some comparator and sorts by it.
What I want to do is to sort the following words firstly *by length* and then by letter order. Help me please.

I didn't find anything about it in Phrases or Dictionary on jsoftware, except from sorting and grading numerical values.

```
   words=: >;:'CLOUD USB NETWORK LAN SERVER FIREWIRE CLIENT PEER'
   ] alpha=: a. {~ (i.26) + a.i.'A'
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
   ;/ words/: alpha i. words
┌────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┐
│CLIENT  │CLOUD   │FIREWIRE│LAN     │NETWORK │PEER    │SERVER  │USB     │
└────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

My first crazy idea is to shift each word to right boundary of the array, e.g.

```
 ABC
DEFG
  XY
```

Then for whitespace assign the extreme ranking (in *y* argument of sorting primitive). And then shift each word back `:D`. It would be highly inefficient, I can't see another J-way.

**Update**
Here is the *Wolfram Language* code for my problem:

```
StringSplit @ "CLOUD USB NETWORK LAN SERVER FIREWIRE CLIENT PEER"
~SortBy~
(Reverse @ ComposeList[{StringLength}, #] &)
```

If I want to prioritize longer words, I just append `Minus @*` to `StringLength`.
Basically my sorting order here is `{{5, "CLOUD"}, {3, "USB"}, {7, "NETWORK"}, ...}`.

I can make the same array in J using `(,.~ #&.>)` applied to boxed words, but how do I use sorting primitives then? Maybe this is the right first step? I'm still not sure, but it sound much better than my first guess `:)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, I have promoted answers suggested in the comments to the main body of the answer.

First of all, I don't think it is a good idea to apply `>` to the list of words because that will add fill which destroys information about the length of each  word. So start with

```
   words=: ;:'CLOUD USB NETWORK LAN SERVER FIREWIRE CLIENT PEER'
```

Then you need a function foo that turns each word into a value that will sort in the order you wish using `\:` or `/:`

```
   words \: foo words
```

will do the trick.  Or, depending on whether you think hooks are pretty or ugly, you could express that as

```
   (/: foo) words
```

My original suggestion for foo used #. to express each word as a single number:

```
   foo=: (128&#.)@(a.&i.)@>
   foo words
18145864388 1403330 345441182148939 1253582 2870553715410 39730390339053893 2322657797972 168911570

   (/: foo) words
┌───┬───┬────┬─────┬──────┬──────┬───────┬────────┐
│LAN│USB│PEER│CLOUD│CLIENT│SERVER│NETWORK│FIREWIRE│
└───┴───┴────┴─────┴──────┴──────┴───────┴────────┘
```

In a comment, Danylo Dubinin pointed out that instead of encoding the word, we can simply catenate the word length to the front of the index vector and sort using that:

```
   (/: (# , a.&i.)@>) words
┌───┬───┬────┬─────┬──────┬──────┬───────┬────────┐
│LAN│USB│PEER│CLOUD│CLIENT│SERVER│NETWORK│FIREWIRE│
└───┴───┴────┴─────┴──────┴──────┴───────┴────────┘
```

Comment: OK, I came up with an appropriate foo.  Here is a function g that turns each word into a number using base 128 (because I'm assuming ascii characters). Naturally, longer words have larger values but within a length only character order matters.

   g=: monad : '128 #. a. i. y'


   (/: g@>) words
┌───┬───┬────┬─────┬──────┬──────┬───────┬────────┐
│LAN│USB│PEER│CLOUD│CLIENT│SERVER│NETWORK│FIREWIRE│
└───┴───┴────┴─────┴──────┴──────┴───────┴────────┘

Comment: My browser doesn't interact with these forms very well. The definition of g should be on its own line

   g=: monad : '128 #. a. i. y'

Comment: Then foo defined as g@>

Comment: And the final application is

   (/: g@>) words

Comment: Michael Berry, thank you, your idea (which I find great!) inspired me for another approach: `(/: (# , a.&i.)@>) words`. Here I just prepend the length to array of symbol codes. It uses more space I believe but it's not limited to certain range and does not do arithmetic. I upvote your answer but could you please make update to the answer rather than comment?

Comment: By the way, to insert `code` you can use backticks **``**